# Count number of Structs in a Struct

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Audio: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let refrenceID: Int
    let channels: [Channel]
}

struct Channel: Hashable, Codable {
    let audio: String
    let panning: Double
    let volume: Double
    let crossfade: Bool
    let random: Bool
    let frequency: Int?
    let period: Int?
}
```

`Audio` can contain any number of structs `Channel`, but I am having a hard time calling and referencing them. I am trying to make each Channel a tab in a Picker().

```
struct AudioAdjust: View {
    var audio: Audio //Read in from JSON file
    var nChannel = 1

    var body: some View {
                Picker("Select Channel to Adjust", selection: channels[0]) {
                    ForEach(channels, id: audio) {
                        Text(nChannel)
                        nChannel += nChannel
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                .padding(.horizontal)
```

Comment: Did my response answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForEach` in SwiftUI doesn't work like a traditional `for` loop in procedural programming. You shouldn't be doing any 'work' like `nChannel += nChannel` inside the loop.

There are a few other issues with the code here -- the selection should be `@State`, you need to iterate over an array, etc.

The following should get you started, but it would also be a great time to check out some SwiftUI tutorials to get the some of the fundamentals of SwiftUI clear.

```
struct AudioAdjust: View {
    var audio: Audio
    @State private var selectedChannel: Audio.ID = 0

    var body: some View {
                Picker("Select Channel to Adjust", selection: $selectedChannel) {
                    ForEach(audio.channels) { channel in
                        Text(channel.audio)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                .padding(.horizontal)
```